# Example of how to use TreeView_SortChildrenCB

Tags: c++

Raymond Chen wrote:

> "The `TreeView` common control does not support moving items to a new parent. If you want to >move an item relative to its siblings (but remain under the same parent), you can use >`TreeView_SortChildrenCB` and pass a custom sort function that orders the children the way you >want."

Is there an example anywhere of exactly how to call `TreeView_SortChildrenCB` to sort according to an arbitrary ordering (e.g., sorting doubles or strings)? The documentation is anything but clear to someone who is an experienced C++ programmer but isn't familiar with this function.

Thanks.

Comment: You presumably have some experience with sort callback functions? Create a sort callback function that compares according to the order you like, and pass it to TreeView_SortChildrenCB as the second parameter. It works basically the same as the last parameter to `qsort`.

Answer (score 0):

First you populate an instance of a TVSORTCB. hParent should be the item in the tree under which you wish to sort, lpfnCompare should be a static function that looks like this

```
int CALLBACK CompareFunc(LPARAM lParam1, LPARAM lParam2, LPARAM lParamSort)
{
    /*your casting of lParams and sorting code here*/
}
```

The intent of the function is to determine if lParam1 is "less than" lParam2.

The lParam value in the structure is whatever you want to be passed as the third argument of your callback  (lParamSort) and can be 0

Then pass the address of that structure instance as the second parameter of TreeView_SortChildrenCB

The 2 arguments that are passed into the callback (lParam1/2) are values you associate with each of the items inserted into the tree. On most, if not all common controls, you can associate an lParam value with each selectable item in the control. In this case, that is the lParam value in the TVITEM structure in the TVINSERTSTRUCT you pass to TreeView_InsertItem ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773898(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Often this is just an index into a table containing strings or some other struct that is comparable. That table would presumably be accessible by casting the 3rd argument of the callback to that table structure if you set the lParam of the TVSORTCB to point to that table.

Sorry if that's not clear. win32 api's tend to over use the lParam mechanism to associate data with practically every handle in the GUI APIs. Don't fall into the trap of allocating strings/structs and assigning the new memory's address into the tree item's lParam. If you fail to delete those allocations for every item in the tree, you'll leak memory.